# Pandas replace and fillna if column begins with part of a string

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering whether there is a way to use the .replace() and .fillna() for columns headers that begin with part of a string.

For example:

```
data['Q5_A'].fillna(value='Not Applicable', inplace=True)
```

This will only apply .fillna() to column Q5_A.

Similarily:

```
data["Q5_S"] = data["Q5_S"].replace(",", "", regex=True)
```

This will only apply .replace() to column Q5_S.

What if I would like it to apply to any columns that have "Q5_" in the header?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `data.columns` to get all the column header and use for loop and if condition  to do the `replace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a for loop and perform all the processes you need as well.

```
for header in data.columns:
    if "Q5" in header:
        data[header].fillna(value='Not Applicable', inplace=True)
        data[header] = data[header].replace(",", "", regex=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, so this would allow multiple strings e.g.: if "Q5" or "Q6" in header:

Answer (score 1):

`Filter` the required columns then do replace/fillna:

```
data.assign(**data.filter(like='Q5_').replace(",", "", regex=True))
```

Alternatively, if you want to modify the dataframe inplace, we can do:

```
cols = data.filter(like='Q5_').columns
data[cols] = data[cols].replace(",", "", regex=True)
```

Comment: The same way for doing `.fillna()` too